# What is switched median filter algorithm? (Digital Image Processing)

Tags: image-processing

I want to use switched median (SM) filter algorithm in some assignment of digital image processing. I searched and searched but I can't find the base algorithm of SM filter.

I would be very thankful for any answer

Thanks

Comment: Try http://dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find this algorithm there too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To briefly explain the version of switched median filter I'm describing

> A pixel value is altered only if it is detected to have been corrupted by impulse noise. The impulse noise is detected using decision mechanism with a pre-set 
>   threshold value and the corrupted pixels alone are subjected to filtering. The window size is increased to achieve better noise removal.

Below is pseudocode for the algorithm:

```
if Amin < Ai,j < Amax{
    Ai,j is a noiseless pixel; no filtering is performed on Ai,j
}else{
    Ai,j is a noisy pixel;determine the median value
}

if median != 0 and median != 255{
    Median filter is performed on Ai,j;
    Ai,j = Amed
}else{
    Median itself is noisy
    Ai,j = Ai-1,j 
}
```

`Ai,j` is the intensity of central pixel inside the filtering window,
`Amin`, `Amax` and `Amed` are the minimum , maximum and median pixel 
value in filtering window of noisy image. `Ai-1,j` is the intensity of the 
already processed immediate top neighboring pixel.

You can read more [here](http://www.ijser.org/researchpaper/switching-median-filter-for-image-enhancement.pdf)

Good luck.

Comment: WOW! It realy helps! Thank you very much.

Comment: I think there is an error in the paper: the second decision should not be `median != 0 and median != 255` but `median != Amin  and median != Amax`. Also in your code is an error: the second ifthenelse condition should be part of the first else branch.